# Where is a good place to learn classical optics for high school competitions?

Tags: optics, visible-light, resource-recommendations, education, lenses

I need to learn basic optics for a high school academic competition. Does anyone know any good places, preferably free and online, to learn the basics of optics, like lenses, angles of incidence, etc.? I can't seem to find an MIT OpenCourseWare course addressing the issue.

Comment: [MIT Optics](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEA084AC2DD3CEC09); [MIT Atomic and optical physics I](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUl4u3cNGP62FPGcyFJkzhqq9c5cHCK32); [MIT Atomic and optical physics II](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUl4u3cNGP62uOSArqLf4vNLiZtgIRm1K)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.khanacademy.org/#physics

Scroll down till #145, that's where optics starts. If you want just lenses, start with the 'virtual image' one.

If not for your online-only request, I would have suggested Resnick-Halliday-Walker. IMHO, that's just about the best book for classical *anything*

Comment: Well, it said "preferably" free and online, not "necessarily," so I think HRW is a fair answer to this question.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Good point.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I like Khan Academy's more wordy explanation - it let's me get an intuitive and quantitative understanding. Also, thanks for the book link although it's a bit out of my means.